# Angular : Unable to Map the date field to format it

Tags: angular

I am subscribing to an observable to get data which works fine in angular 8. I need to format  the date when using mapping I get error saying

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

So I believe adding the map operator and changed the return type. I am not sure what's wrong in the way that I have implemented the map. Could somebody let me know?

```
export interface IPersonNote {
    id: number;
    personId: number;
    note: string;
    authorId: number;
    authorName: string;
    fileName: string;
    mimeType: string;
    alias: string;
    createdBy: string;
    createdDate: Date;
}
```

Original method

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
public personNotes: IPersonNote[];

   loadPersonNotes() {
        this.isCurrentUser = this.id !== this.userService.getCurrentUser().id;
        this.userService.getPersonNote(this.id)
          .subscribe((x: IPersonNote[]) => {

            this.personNotes = x;
          });
      }
```

Modified method

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
public personNotes: IPersonNote[];

loadPersonNotes() {
    this.isCurrentUser = this.id !== this.userService.getCurrentUser().id;
    this.userService.getPersonNote(this.id)
      .pipe(map(note => <any>{
        createdDate: format(note.createdDate, 'Do MMM YYYY'),
      }))
      .subscribe((x: IPersonNote[]) => {

        this.personNotes = x;
      });
  }
```

UI

```
<div *ngIf="personNotes">
<div class="portlet-body">
    <ul class="tier-history">
      <li *ngFor="let note of personNotes">
        <span class="tier-title"> {{ note.authorName }} </span>
        <span class="tier-dates">
            {{ note.created }} 
        </span>
        <span class="tier-title"> {{ note.note }} </span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Service

```
public getPersonNote = (id: number): Observable<IPersonNote[]> =>
this.http.get<IPersonNote[]>(`${this.baseUrl}person-note/${id}`)
```

Error after implementing the proposed solution

```
Types of parameters 'x' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type '{ created: string; id: number; personId: number; note: string; authorId: number; authorName: string; fileName: string; mimeType: string; alias: string; createdBy: string; }[]' is 
not assignable to type 'IPersonNote[]'.
      Type '{ created: string; id: number; personId: number; note: string; authorId: number; authorName: string; fileName: string; mimeType: string; alias: string; createdBy: string; }' is 
not assignable to type 'IPersonNote'.
        Types of property 'created' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

49       .subscribe((x: IPersonNote[]) => {
                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Why not format the date during the output? `{{ note.created | date : 'Do MMM YYYY' }}`

Comment: at the template you render the date liek this `{{ note.created }}` but it 's must be `{{ note.createdDate }}` base of the interface  

Answer (score 0):

The map operator in your question returns a single object and doesn't change the data and return it. That is why **ngFor** throws an error: because data is not an iterable object.

I assume you get an array of `IPersonNote` so I run the array map method to just update the property `createdDate` based off array item n.createDate value.

This will return a new array and `createDate` will be based off the format method's return value.

```js
note.map(n => ({  ...n, createdDate: format(n.createdDate, 'Do MMM YYYY') }) )
```

The updated loadPersonNotes method looks like this:

```js
loadPersonNotes() {
  this.isCurrentUser = this.id !== this.userService.getCurrentUser().id;
  this.userService.getPersonNote(this.id)
    .pipe(
        map(
            note => note.map(n =>({...n,createdDate: format(n.createdDate, 'Do MMM YYYY')}))
        )
    ) 
   .subscribe((x: IPersonNote[]) => {
  
        this.personNotes = x;
      });
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use an arrow function, you can't output an object like that. Either wrap the output in parentheses, e.g. `.map(n => ({ ...n, createdDate: .. }))` or use `return`, e.g. `.map(n => { return { ...n, createdDate: ... }; })`.

Comment: I am getting syntactical error with the above. error at line .subscribe((x: IPersonNote[]) => {               .

Comment: Error. No overload matches this call

Comment: @Tom I have test the answer like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4lbsxg and it 's working fine , you may have another problem 

Comment: Very strange. I can see your example and the error that i am getting is updated in the post

Comment: Not sure why the left hand created is showing type string

Comment: You need to update personNotes data type like this `public personNotes: IPersonNote[];`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205618/discussion-between-tom-and-muhammed-albarmavi).